# Sum of array in C

Tags: c, arrays, visual-studio, loops, double

I'm working on a small program for school and can't get my array of doubles to sum properly.  The specific error I'm getting is

```
warning C4244: 'return': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

on the line where sum is returned.  And the sum displayed is gibberish.

The code is intended to:

1. fill an array of doubles with user input,
2. print the doubles on the screen in a column,
3. add up all the doubles in the array, and
4. print the sum onto the screen.

#### Code

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1 
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 15

void FillArray(double a[], int *i); 
void PrintArray(double a[], int i);  
SumArray(double a[], int *i);        
int main()
{
    double input[15];             
    int input_size;
    double sum;


    FillArray(input, &input_size);         
    PrintArray(input, input_size);       
    sum = SumArray(input, &input_size);     
    printf("The sum is %f\n", sum);          
    return 0;

}

void FillArray(double a[], int *i)         
{
    int k;
    printf("Filling an array of doubles\n");                      
    printf("How many doubles do you want to enter (<15)\n");        
    scanf(" %d", i);                                               

    for (k = 0; k <*i; k++)                                      
    {
        printf("Enter double:\n");                                
        scanf("%lf", &a[k]);                                      
    }
}

void PrintArray(double a[], int i)                        
{
    int k;
    printf("Printing an array of integers:\n");             
    for (k = 0; k<i; k++)                                   
    {
        printf("%f\n", a[k]);                                
    }
    printf("\n");
}

SumArray(double a[], int *i)                        
{
    int k;
    double sum = 0;
    for (k = 0; k<*i; k++);
    {
        sum +=a[k];
    }
    return (sum) ;
}
```

Comment: Please do not correct the question, people will have no idea what you asked about. Correct the actual code. Rolled back.

Comment: you shouldn't change the original code in your question to reflect the fix. This alters the question, masks the original problem, and can make comments/answers appear out of context and confuse others who come along later.

Comment: When compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.  There is no reason to try to run the code if the compiler is outputting warnings about the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `double SumArray(...)` instead of merely `SumArray(...)` where you declare and define the function.  If you do not specify a return type, `int` is assumed.  Specifically:

```
  void FillArray(double a[], int *i); 
  void PrintArray(double a[], int i);  
  double SumArray(double a[], int *i);        
/*^^^^^^-- add return type*/
  int main()
```

and

```
  double SumArray(double a[], const int numElements)
/*^^^^^^- same deal*/ /* also ^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^ */

  {
      int k;
      double sum = 0.0; /* Edit 3: 0.0 rather than 0 for clarity */
      for (k = 0; k < numElements; ++k) /* no ; here!  --- Edit 3: ++k for speed and good practice */
      {            /* ^^^^^^^^^^^ */
          sum +=a[k];
      }
      return (sum) ;
  }
```

**Edit** Also, you can use `const int numElements` instead of `int *i` in `SumArray`.  You don't need to modify the value inside `SumArray`, so you don't need the `*` and you can specify `const`.  And it's a good practice to give your variables descriptive names, e.g., `numElements` instead of `i`.  That will help you understand your own code when you have to maintain it later!  (Ask me how I know. ;) )

To use this, you also need to change the call in `main` to remove the `&`:

```
sum = SumArray(input, input_size);
                   /* ^ no & here */
```

**Edit 2** As @BLUEPIXY pointed out, the trailing `;` on the `for` loop was misplaced.  As a result, the `{}` block ran once, after the loop had completed.  That would be a significant cause of the "gibberish" you saw: the effect was to set `k=numElements` and then set `sum=a[numElements]`, which was a non-existent element.  So the `sum` was being set to whatever random memory contents happened to be after `a`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Good catch - fixed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I changed it but my sum is still wrong. It gives a very large negative number.

Comment: @C45M99S Just updated per BLUEPIXY - did you try the latest without the `;` on the `for` line?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That fixed it. Don't know how I missed that.Thanks alot